# Add worksheet name to rows in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I got a workbook with 100 sheets and I want to iterate in every sheet, and where cells of column C are not null to print the worksheet name on the corresponding b column.

The original workSheet 1 is:

```
a    | b   | c 
123 | null | John
345 | null | Arya
678 | null | Sansa
```

and i want it to be transformed to

```
a   | b      | c 
123 | Sheet1 | John
345 | Sheet1 | Arya
678 | Sheet1 | Sansa
```

I want this loop to iterate in every worksheet of the workbook and the range in each sheet is not standard. Here's the code I created by reading various posts but it doesn't work

```
Dim LastRow As Long
 Sub Correction()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Integer
   x = Sheets.Count
    For j = x To 1 Step -1
     LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            ActiveSheet.Cells("B", i) = ActiveSheet.Name
        Next i
      Next j
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm novice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Correction()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i, LastRow As Integer
Dim Sht As Worksheet

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    LastRow = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            Sht.Cells(i, 2) = Sht.Name
        Next i
Next Sht

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! Do you mind if you do a little breakdown for me in order to understand it completely and not to bother you people with silly questions?

Comment: First, you had the Dim LastRow before the Sub, so that didn't do anything for you.  If you are using Option Explicit, it would have been an error, but it would default to a number otherwise.  Secondly, Sheets is a collection in the Workbooks property.  No need to create a loop with Step when you can cycle through the collection.  You can read more about collections, very useful.  Thirdly, I changed the cell annotation to be the standard (Row Number, Column Number).  Maybe more style than anything, but it is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it should be `xlDown` instead of `xlUp` in this row:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
```

`xlUp` would tell VBA to go to the topmost end of column C (which would be row 1). Then you're iterating from row 2 to 1.

Not sure though, haven't been using VBA for a long time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, the original way (xlUp) is correct - it goes to the last row and then goes up to the last row containing data.  It's the same as going to the last row and pressing Ctrl+Up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Correction()
Dim i, j, lastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws in Worksheets
    With ws
         lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
         For i = 2 to lastRow
            If .Cells(i,3) <> "null" Then .Cells(i,2) = ws.Name
         Next 
    End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Tom Thanks for your help but your solution didn' t work. It didn' t do anything to the worksheet.

Comment: Code works fine for me. What's the exact String you are looking for? Is it "null" or is the cell empty?

Comment: @ Tom It worked but the script considers as used range the range defined by A column not C column. Thanks for your help!